# Displaying current day twice

Tags: javascript, html

I have used javascript and html for the creation of my date dropdown. Onloading my php file it shows today's date. But the problem is , it shows today's day twice.
For Eg: If today's date is 12-2-2015 It has options for DAY in dropdown as "1,2,3....11,12,12,14... and so on. Here 13th day is not shown.

Can anyone please help me correct the dates.
Here is my javascript:

```
 var monthtext=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield){
  var today=new Date()
  var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
  var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
  var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
  var thisday=1;
  for (var i=0; i<31; i++) {
    dayfield.options[i]=new Option(thisday, thisday)
    thisday+=1;
  }

  dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day

  for (var m=0; m<12; m++) monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])

  monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month

  var thisyear=1999
  for (var y=0; y<45; y++){
    yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
    thisyear+=1
  }
  yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
}
```

This is my html code:

```
<tr><br><td>Date of Diagnosis</td><td>
  <select id="daydropdown" name="daydropdown"></select> 
  <select id="monthdropdown" name="monthdropdown"></select>
  <select id="yeardropdown" name="yeardropdown"></select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
    window.onload=function() {
      populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown")
    }
  </script></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't see any PHP code! Is this related to php? -> Show us your php code

Comment: Try using underscore function _.uniq(), example:  _.uniq([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]); // 1,2,3,4...or use arr.filter

Comment: Why have a for loop and then increment a different variable? That's the whole point of a for. Instead why not do this ``for (var thisday = 1; thisday <= 31; thisday++)`` and then ``dayfield.options[thisday - 1] = new Op..``

Comment: @JLevett, Glad to see you allowed for 31 days in a month. OP's code, and several others in this thread, only allow 1-30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need below changes in your code.
`today.getDate()` is 12 and where `dayfield.options[12]` is 13th date. So it is replacing 13th with 12th and repeat 12th twice and remove 13.

Replace

```
`dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day`
```

with

```
dayfield.options[today.getDate()-1]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting an existing option for the current date, you are adding a new option. So for instance on your day field, you are adding numbers 1 through 31 and then adding a new option for the current day.

I would check for the current day during the for loop and added a selected attribute

```
var today = new Date();
for (var i=0; i<31; i++) {
  dayfield.options[i]=new Option(thisday, thisday)

  if(today.getDate() == thisday) {
     dayfield.selectedIndex = i;
  }
  thisday+=1;
}
```

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekw5vkpw/)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the line

```
dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
```

This is adding inserting a second copy of todays date into the slot for tomorrow. If you look at your loop inserting dates:

```
var thisday=1;
for (var i=0; i<31; i++) {
  dayfield.options[i]=new Option(thisday, thisday)
  thisday+=1;
}
```

You will see the dayfield.options array is zero based, that is the first element is in position zero, you will also see that `thisday` starts at 1 so this will be equivalent to

```
dayfield.options[0] = new Option(1,1);
dayfield.options[1] = new Option(2,2);
dayfield.options[2] = new Option(3,3);
dayfield.options[3] = new Option(4,4);
....
```

Assumming today was the 2nd of the month:

```
dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
// would have the effect of
dayfield.options[2] = new Option(2,2,true,true);
```

If you look above you can see option[2] was the slot for the 3rd before this line was carried out.

To fix this you should either use:

```
// Note the -1
dayfield.options[today.getDate() -1] = new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true); //select today's day
```

Or set selected in your for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<31; i++) {
  var selected = thisday == today.getDate();
  dayfield.options[i]=new Option(thisday, thisday, selected, selected);
  thisday+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this and just use the iterator variable.

```
for (var i=1; i<32; i++) {
    dayfield.options[i]=new Option(i, i);
}
```

Even better, use this to get the number of days in a month:

```
var daysInMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
```